# Baby monitor has more static when toilet is flushed?

Tags: radio

I have a baby monitor in the basement of my house, and it's picking up the signal of the microphone transmitter on the second floor. It's not a great quality monitor, so there's always a small amount of static if I turn up the volume on the monitor.

Whenever someone flushes the toilet on the second floor, the amount of audible static on the monitor noticeably increases during the flush. I'm trying to figure out why that could be.

I thought perhaps the water temporarily in the drain pipes over the basement could be changing/blocking the carrier signal of the transmitter (weakening the signal and allowing more static to seem there). But is something else going on here?

Comment: This is an engineering question, but what basically happens is that the babymonitor detects that there is a noise and it increases the signal gain, so that the baby or child can be heard better. It's a feature engineered into the electronics of the device. There is no actual physics here.

Comment: I would think that you are just hearing a bad reproduction of the flushing sound.

Comment: I believe Curious one pegged the solution to the mystery. Of course you could test the hypothesis by introducing another source of sound to see if it also invokes noise.